# Adjective or adverb? Confusion!

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, adverbs

Could someone point out for me that which of the following choices is accurate?

- Even though I understand that my comments were offensive, you should cut me a break because I only meant them (joking/jokingly).

First, I picked "joking" but it turned out that the answer key told the answer was "jokingly". As a result, I got flummoxed because I thought that the meaning of the word "meant" in the above sentence was exactly similar to the word "considered"; hence according to my thought, the answer should have been "joking". Anyway, could somebody explain this situation for me explicitly? I will appreciate any help from you guys!

Comment: *meant* here does not mean *considered* but rather *intended to be taken* as in “I only intended them to be taken as a joke” thus *jokingly*

Answer (score -2):

I only meant them jokingly.

How did you mean them? Jokingly.

A lot of adverbs can be easily identified by asking yourself how, in which manner/degree, etc.

Answer (score -2):

Adverb describes verbs -

> Even though I understand that my comments were offensive(verb), you should
>   cut me a break because I only meant them jokingly(adverb).